# Teamviewer conflicted with JNDI - use higher port numbers for outgoing (win7)

Tags: javascript, jndi, teamviewer

Teamviewer established an outgoing connection using the local port 1098 which is also the JNDI port.

I spent 2 hours until I realized what the error was because I was focusing in the resulting exceptions, e.g. :

```
Exception: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: Cannot set transactional mode, error is setAutoCommit() is not allowed - use TransactionHelper instead
    javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: 

Cannot set transactional mode, error is setAutoCommit() is not allowed - use TransactionHelper instead
         at daoframework.daofactory.transactions.LocalUserTransaction.begin(LocalUserTransaction.java:78)
```

Is there any way to block teamviewer from using this port?

Found using:

```
$ netstat -aon | grep 1098
  TCP    XX.XXX.XX.XX:1098      XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:80      ESTABLISHED     2596
```

And then looking up the PID in taskmanager.

### Update

It seems this more more of a windows 7 problem. In windows vista and beyond:

> To comply with Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)
>   recommendations, Microsoft has increased the dynamic client port range
>   for outgoing connections in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008.
>   The new default start port is 49152, and the default end port is
>   65535. **This is a change from the configuration of earlier versions of Windows that used a default port range of 1025 through 5000.**

**Is there a way to patch windows 7 to use higher port numbers for outgoing connections?**

### Update2

My windows 7 machine was indeed running with a low port limit.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 1025
Number of Ports : 64510
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851

You adjust this range by using the netsh command, as follows:

> ```
> netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> set dynamic <tcp|udp> start=number num=range
> ```
>
> This command sets the dynamic port range for TCP. The start port is
>   number, and the total number of ports is range. The following are
>   sample commands:
>
> ```
> netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=1000
> netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=1000
> ```

Set the range to the following:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=49152 num=16384
```

Finally, even though ephemeral ports should be short lived, an application such as teamviewer may use `keep-alive` requests and hold onto the port for a much longer time.